# I cannot manage to insert multiple rows when having multiple fields to get data from

Tags: t-sql

I ran into a problem with regards to trying to insert multiple rows in a table at once. I know it sounds easy, but here is the twist. The procedure itself gets data from a trigger, and the trigger returns a number of rows. So i need to make 1 insert statement to insert those rows and some other data. here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a01].[usp_raiseFriendAlerts]
(@AccountA UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @AccountB UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @typeID TINYINT;
    DECLARE @notificationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
    DECLARE @accountAName NVARCHAR(356);
    DECLARE @accountBName NVARCHAR(356);

SET @typeID = ( SELECT  typeID
                FROM    [a01].[tbl_notificationTypes]
                WHERE   typeName = 'Added friend');

SET @accountAName = (   SELECT  accountUsername
                        FROM    [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
                        WHERE   accountID = @AccountA);

SET @accountBName = (   SELECT  accountUsername
                        FROM    [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
                        WHERE   accountID = @AccountB);

DECLARE @AccountIDZZ UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

SET @AccountIDZZ = (SELECT  friendAccountID
                    FROM    [a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts](@AccountA, @AccountB)

                    EXCEPT

                    SELECT  targetAccountID
                    FROM    [a01].[tbl_blockedAccounts]);

INSERT INTO [a01].[tbl_notificationsInbox] (notificationID, notificationMessage, notificationDate, accountID, typeId)
    VALUES (@notificationID, @accountAName + ' is now friends with ' + @accountBName, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), @AccountIDZZ , @typeID)

END;
GO
```

Comment: The main problem is where there is the @AccountIDZZ. that is my test code that i was trying to work on

Comment: But @AccountIDZZ is singular and that can return multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a01].[usp_raiseFriendAlerts]
(
    @AccountA UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @AccountB UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE     @typeID TINYINT
                , @notificationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
                , @accountAName NVARCHAR(356)
                , @accountBName NVARCHAR(356)
                , @AccountIDZZ UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    SELECT      @typeID = typeID
    FROM        [a01].[tbl_notificationTypes]
    WHERE       typeName = 'Added friend';

    SELECT      @accountAName = accountUsername
    FROM        [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
    WHERE       accountID = @AccountA;

    SELECT      @accountBName = accountUsername
    FROM        [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
    WHERE       accountID = @AccountB; 

    INSERT INTO     [a01].[tbl_notificationsInbox] 
                    (
                        notificationID
                        , notificationMessage
                        , notificationDate
                        , accountID
                        , typeId
                    )
    SELECT          @notificationID
                    , @accountAName + ' is now friends with ' + @accountBName
                    , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
                    , AIDZZ.accountID
                    , @typeID
    FROM            (
                        SELECT      friendAccountID AS 'accountID'
                        FROM        [a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts](@AccountA, @AccountB)

                        EXCEPT

                        SELECT      targetAccountID AS 'accountID'
                        FROM        [a01].[tbl_blockedAccounts]
                    ) AS AIDZZ

END;
GO
```